# Adding Boolean outputs to a función in R

Tags: r, boolean

Here is the question for the assignment :

Problem 3. Practice using functions. Recall the syntax of a function is:
function name = function(inputs){ code here }
Hint: For both parts of this problem it may be useful to reuse parts of code you wrote in Problem 2.
(a) Write a function called find positive that takes in a vector of numbers and returns a vector of booleans called “output” based on whether or not the entries of the vector are positive or negative. Check your work by running your function on “data” and comparing the output to “data > 0”. To get started, make a separate R Block for your function and use the following shell:
find positive <- function(input){ # your code here [...]
...
your code here [...] return(output) }
(b) Write a function called “clean data” that takes in a vector of numbers and returns a vector called “ret” of same length such that ret[i] = 1 if the input vector ith element was positive, and ret[i] = 0 otherwise. To get started, make a separate R Block for your function and use the following shell:
clean data <- function(input){ # your code here [...]
...
your code here [...] return(ret) }

Here is the code I wrote (which is wrong)

````
```{r}
data <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
output = c()
find_positive <- for(i in data){
  if(i > 0){
    i = TRUE
    output(i)
  }else{
    i = FALSE
    output(i)
  }
}
```
````

Comment: just do `output <- data > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doens't work, but it is not wrong. Just don't try to overwrite i within your if-function.

Maybe you get a new a idea for b) with this block:

```
find_positive <- function(data) {
output <-  c()
  
for(i in data){
  if(i > 0){
    res <- TRUE
    output <- c(output, res)
  }else{
    res <- FALSE
    output <- c(output, res)
  }
}

return(output)
}

find_positive(data)
```